# Newbit to Linux and Pop OS

Tags: command-line, boot, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

So I am running Pop OS 20.10, though I initially installed 20.04 (seems like an autoupdate), well now I have a bunch of files/softwares I can no longer update because this happens

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.197+system76~1620141009~20.10~f54d87c) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-7614-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas without needing to wipe system on a fresh reinstall?

As for what steps I tried, I followed this, inputting every command individually

https://support.system76.com/articles/package-manager-pop/